# I cannot edit a field with mechanize

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, mechanize, mechanize-ruby

I am developing a Rails application and I am using mechanize to automate the changing of a profile. Currently I am trying to change a field date that has some sort of mask, as it only displays the format. (dd/mm/yyyy). It has two fields: Birth_Date_Visible, text input, and Birth_Date, hidden_field. I cannot change the hidden field as doing so and submitting the form raises me a 500 server error: unhandled response.

Any ideas on how to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem may be that you didn't change hidden control readonly attr.

From [Mechanize FAQ:](http://wwwsearch.sourceforge.net/mechanize/faq.html)

How do I change INPUT TYPE=HIDDEN field values (for example, to emulate the effect of JavaScript code)?
As with any control, set the control’s readonly attribute false.

```
form.find_control("foo").readonly = False # allow changing .value of control foo
form.set_all_readonly(False) # allow changing the .value of all controls
```

Comment: hello Nikita, by foo meaning what? I am sorry but I am trying to use this on my code with no succes..

Comment: @ingalcala "foo" is the name of control element.
Users interact with forms through named controls.
For example this is a control element named control2 composed of 2 checkboxes :
`<input type="checkbox" name="control2" value="foo" id="cbe1">
<input type="checkbox" name="control2" value="bar" id="cbe2">`